# Intellij vim emulation backspace does not work

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, backspace

I started using Intellij for learning Java. I love the vim shortcuts. So started using the IdeaVim plugin for Intellij but when I press backspace in the end of the line. The cursor just goes one Line Up instead of removing the indentation of the line.

Comment: Please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you are in Insert mode? `<BS>` in Normal mode moves the cursor to the left (or end of previous line of on first character of line).

Comment: @JakeGrossman Yeah

Comment: Could you please share log?

Comment: what do you mean by share the log?

Comment: Could you post idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE on some file sharing  online service?